# Magento 2 Payment method for certain Customer groups

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

Is it possible to choose payment method to certain customer groups?
In **Magento 1** there are some codes to add payment modules, like that any ways in **Magento 2** ? without using plugins?

Comment: If you are ready to purchase the extension you can check out [Payment & Shipping By Customer Group](https://www.mageants.com/customer-group-based-shipping-and-payment-method-for-magento-2.html) extension.

Answer (score 7):

Let’s create a module.
Step 1) Create folders like this.

```
app/code/Pits/PaymentMethod/etc/
app/code/Pits/PaymentMethod/Observer/
```

Step 2) Declare your module

```
app/code/Pits/PaymentMethod/etc/module.xml.
```

Paste the following code in the above file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Pits_PaymentMethod" setup_version="2.0.0" /></config>
```

Step 4 ) Create registration file.
        **app/code/Pits/PaymentMethod/registration.php**
Paste the below code.

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Pits_PaymentMethod',
    __DIR__
);
```

Step 5)Run the below command in the command line

php bin/magento module:enable Pits_PaymentMethod

```
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Step 6)Lets create events.xml file

app/code/Pits/PaymentMethod/etc/events.xml

Paste the below code in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="Pits_PaymentMethod_DisabledPgByCustomergroup" instance="Pits\PaymentMethod\Observer\DisabledPgByCustomergroup" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Step 7)Lets create observer file

```
app/code/Pits/PaymentMethod/Observer/DisabledPgByCustomergroup.php
```

Paste the below code in it.

```
<?php
namespace Pits\PaymentMethod\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
class DisabledPgByCustomergroup implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $result          = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote           = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $this->_logger->info($method_instance->getCode());
        /* If Cusomer  group is match then work */
        if (null !== $quote && $quote->getCustomerGroupId() != 4) {
            /* Disable All payment gateway  exclude Your payment Gateway*/
            if ($method_instance->getCode() == 'purchaseorder') {
                $result->setData('is_available', false);
            }
        }
        /*else{
        if($method_instance->getCode() =='purchaseorder'){
        $result->setData('is_available', true);

        }
        }*/
    }
}
```

Step 8)Run this in command line

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: This answer is not related at all to the original question.

Answer (score 4):

For this, you need a create module which will fire **an observer on event** `payment_method_is_active` .

And on this observer,you can ***disabled any payment method basis of Customer group*** .

> ```
> <?php
> namespace Devamitbera\DisabledPgByCustomergroup\Observer;
>
> use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
> use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
> use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
>
> class ObserverforDisabledPaymentgateway implements ObserverInterface
> {
>     public function __construct() {}
>
>     /**
>      *
>      * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
>     {
>       $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
>       $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
>       $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
>       /* If Cusomer  group is match then work */
>       if(null !== $quote &&  $quote->getCustomerGroupId() =='YOUR_CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID'  ){
>           /* Disable All payment gateway  exclude Your payment Gateway*/
>           if($method_instance->getCode() !='YOUR_PAYMENT_METHOD_CODE'){
>                $result->isAvailable = false;
>           }
>       }
>
>     }
>
> }
> ```

### Note:

Here , i have **Disabled all payment payment gateways** excluding Your gateways when a particular  customer group have order placing

Comment: Amit, Thanks for the answer,
But my module not working as I expected, can you check here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0NGKxAic15YUV8wQmwtazgzU1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: okay. but it not good idea to

Comment: Yea I know but that's very difficult to write/read entire module code/structure in comment, so please....

Comment: Amit, any word, please?

Comment: why rewrite controller ? it is an observer

Comment: check module AT https://github.com/devamitbera/Magento2-extension/tree/master/Magento%202%20Payment%20method%20for%20certain%20Customer%20group

Comment: @AmitBera I followed your method. But even after isAvailable is set false, the payment methods are listed

Comment: may be any other observer is enabling the your pg

Comment: @AmitBera All the payment methods are listed but only the 'place order' button are disabled for other payment methods except the 'YOUR_PAYMENT_METHOD_CODE' method

Comment: Quote is always null in the observer method