# Payment Method show according Customer Group in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, customer-group

How to show payment method on checkout page according to customer group in magento2. Please help me if any one have this solution.

Comment: Please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143022/magento-2-payment-method-for-certain-customer-groups

Comment: Thanks @RamkishanSuthar
Your suggestion is work for me.

Comment: Great Bro, Happy Coding :)